# PIC12F508 saving last count of compressor

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I have this project which is aircon controller and I used PIC12F508 as microcontroller, the operation of this project is that the compressor will turn on for 1hr and after it will stop for 5 minutes and the problem is the pic will reset and it will count again for 1hr.

My goal in this project is that when the time the pic will reset I want to save the last time or count and when it turns on again it will count the remaining time within that 1 hr . I have researched the possible solution and EEPROM can help but I used PIC12F508 which does not have EEPROM, is there any other way aside from EEPROM but still I'll used PIC12F508? thanks

---

This the code I used MPLAB X and XC8 compiler:

```
/* * File: controller.c * Author: Jeaneth * * Created on July 30, 2016, 10:44 AM */
include
include

// PIC12F508 Configuration Bit Settings
include

// CONFIG
pragma config OSC = IntRC // Oscillator Selection bits (internal RC oscillator)
pragma config WDT = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
pragma config CP = OFF // Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
pragma config MCLRE = ON // GP3/MCLR Pin Function Select bit (GP3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)

void main()

{ for(;;)

{

    TRIS = 0b000000;
    GP0 = 0; //LED OFF
    GP1 = 0; //COMPRESSOR OFF
    GP0 = 1; // LED ON
    GP1 = 1; // COMPRESSOR ON
    runcomp();
    GP1 = 0; //COMPRESSOR OFF
    stop();

}

}

int minute()

{

for(int i =1; i>0; i--)
_delay(1000000);
return 0;

}

int runcomp()

{

for(int x =1; x>0; x--)
    minute();
return 0;

} int stop()

{ for(int y =1 ; y>0; y--) minute(); return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post schematic of your current setup and the code you wrote for your PIC. Otherwise we can't figure out what is going wrong and what measures should be taken.

Answer (score 3):

In XC8 you can set a global or static variable to be *persistent*. These variables are not automatically cleared at startup like others are, so they retain their value across reboots (not across power-off though of course).

> **5.4.8.1 PERSISTENT TYPE QUALIFIER**
>
> By default, any C variables that are not explicitly initialized are cleared on startup. This is consistent with the definition of the C language. However, there are occasions where it is desired for some data to be preserved across a Reset. The `persistent` type qualifier (or `__persistent`) is used to qualify variables that should not be cleared by the runtime startup code.
>
> In addition, any persistent variables will be stored in a different area of memory to other variables. Different psects are used to hold these objects. See 5.15.2 Compiler-Generated Psects for more information.
>
> This type qualifier cannot be used on variables of class auto; however, statically defined local variables can be qualified persistent. For example, you should write:
>
> `void test(void)
>   {
>    static persistent int intvar; /* must be static */
>    // ...
>   }`
>
> If the xc8 option, `--STRICT` is used, you cannot use the `persistent` qualifier, but you can continue to use `__persistent`.

Of course one "issue" with this is you don't get a power-on default of 0 for your counter - the actual power-on value may be completely random. So you can try examining the `STATUS` register to try and work out in what way the chip has started up, or give a manual reset option to the user in some way.